# Online wide-field star cameras?

Tags: amateur-observing, photography

Where can I find a large list of online star cameras with wide fields of view?

http://www.itelescope.net/all-sky-cameras is one example, but the images are fairly low resolution and there aren't many of them.

Is there a better site or sites to see wide-field star images?

I realize there are several online telescopes, but they all have a small limited field of view (which makes sense), so you can only see small portions of the sky at once, not the entire sky as above.